# Some of the youtube videos are not playing in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api

I want to play the youtube video in my app. I have tried all the different way but not able to play video. 
Video that are not playing

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuZE_IRwLNI
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyXtoTLLcDk

**1. Simple load request with UIWebView**

it fail with Error

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDXWW5vX-64"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
**Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed.**
```

**2. Embedding youtube Video**

```
    NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                           <html>\
                                <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\
                                    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>\
                                    <script type='text/javascript'>\
                                        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\
                                        {\
                                            ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})\
                                        }\
                                        function onPlayerReady(a)\
                                        { \
                                            a.target.playVideo(); \
                                        }\
                                    </script>\
                                    <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%d' height='%d' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'>\
                                </body>\
                           </html>", 300, 200, @"uuZE_IRwLNI"];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

**Here its just keep loading not able to play**

**3. Extracting Video  URL**

```
LBYouTubeExtractor* extractor = [[LBYouTubeExtractor alloc]initWithID:[self getVideoID] quality:1];
extractor.delegate = self;
[extractor startExtracting];
```

**But here is same reasult**

Comment: i have tried the first one, i can't play it in my web browser neither, since it is not allowed to be played in my geographical region. Maybe similar error?

Comment: So is there any way to play within my application?

Comment: if they are locked for a geographical region the only way to play them is to sue a proxy server in another geo region...

Comment: if it is locked then it should not play in my browser but its playing.  are you talking about proxy server it is possible in IOS?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, calling

```
[videoView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO]
```

Will fix the issue you are facing till Google fix the problem on their end.